# Using pyodbc, and html.py to generate a table

Tags: python

I just started to play around with python, and i really like it. I am able to connect to my database using pydobc and print the results. However, i need help taking the next step to placing the information in a table in a 'form'

```
import pyodbc
connection = pyodbc.connect(MY STRING)
cur = connection.cursor() 
cur.execute("select top(10) May07Control.seq, May07Control.member from dbo.May07Control")
for row in cur:
    print "member: %s"% row.member
    print "seq: %s"% row.seq

##OR the one-line way

cur.execute("select May07Control.seq, May07Control.member from dbo.May07Control")
resultList = [(row.member, row.seq) for row in cur]
```

Comment: 1) What sort of table -- a GUI? an HTML table? a PDF report? 2) This has nothing to do with the database, right?

Comment: at this point i would be happy with either, but my goal is to use html

Comment: no the database works actually, it connected and it printed everything in the idle, so that was good.

Comment: @MyHead: yes, that was my point: the database has nothing to do with the question. You are asking how to format some data in an HTML table; it doesn't matter where the data came from! Consider rewriting your question to something like "How to generate HTML tables from Python?"

Comment: Have you tried either of a templating engine or a grid control yet?

Comment: I can build a table with html.py, but i do not know how to integrate it with pyodbc

Comment: You don't. You pass the structures to the template engine and let it do its thing.

Comment: @MyHead: `print HTML.table(resultList)`

Comment: i guess it was so simple it went over my head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you're running Python through IDLE and you're aiming at a browser view/interface.  The next step is to get a development server running on your local machine. All the template engines come with cookbook instructions on how to do this.  [Bottle](http://bottle.paws.de/docs/dev/index.html) is a very simple example.

I personally use the development servers that come with Google App Engine, and PyDev in Eclipse, and you could potentially use the [included Python server](http://docs.python.org/library/simplehttpserver.html#module-SimpleHTTPServer).

Answer (score 1):

If you need data-driven presentation in a browser, I (and a lot of other people) would strongly suggest Django http://www.djangoproject.com/.